MacOS - Can't control-click for right-click
On my MacBook Pro, control-click for right mouse is setup and works in other apps but not in Blender (two finger tap is way too slow).
Older posts suggests control-click might not be supported in Blender.
Questions...

Is control-click supported yet?
If not, how to I search or request the feature get supported?

Any help much appreciated. Cheers, Ben

For suggestions and feature requests use https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect or https://blenderartists.org
